# Give a object attribute a value with several html inputs in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a form for my object '@student' and an attribute called ':base', what i want is to give the attribute a value using 4 html inputs one for type, one for color, and the other two for another specifications so that in the end I have a result like this :base = Wood red 3D green_background 
the type input will give the wood value, the color input red, etc etc.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I would add fields in the database for each value (color, material, ...) as a String so something like `rails g migration AddFieldsToStudent color:string material:string all_combined:string` then `rake db:migrate`

In your Model you could then add those string into the "super" string like:

```
before_create :super_string

def super_string
   self.all_combined = self.color + " " + self.material
end
```

Something like that?

Comment: Yes! thats exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! :)